# Why is my fancy font selection overriding CM in this way?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern

Every once in a while, I dabble in unconventional font choices. The fact that I do it only once in a while means that I am very hazy on the mechanisms. I was reminded today of one of the other reasons why I'm only hazy on it: the documentation provided by major resources is not very consistent.

While looking up calligraphic fonts on the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/), I was pleased to discover [Lobster Two](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/lobstertwo), which is part of the TeXLive distribution and seems a very nice font to use in small doses. Here's what the LaTeX font catalogue has to say about its usage:

> ### Usage
>
> ```
> \usepackage{LobsterTwo}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> ```
>
> ### Style examples
>
> ```
> \LobsterTwo
> ```
>
> [image: Sample text for LobserTwo font]

This strongly suggests to me that LobsterTwo will not make itself the main font selection, and that the macro `\LobsterTwo` may be used (as with `\sffamily` I suppose). However, when I try it out in a simple document, the behaviour is not what I would expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{LobsterTwo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

{\LobsterTwo Yay, a new font!}

Hey, wait, \underline{this} isn't Computer Modern \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image: Surprising (to me) output from the minimal example]

I don't *always* get this behaviour when trying out new fonts, and in fact I suspect that when I've encountered this behaviour in the past I've simply given up trying to use the font in question. So it's probably a question of learning what the correct workflow is for using a font which is already included in one's TeX distribution.

I could of course add some code immediately after `\begin{document}` which forces a font selection to Computer Modern.
However, this would have to be modified in documents where I choose instead to use, e.g., Palatino or Times.
(The packages for these fonts behave in the same way as LobsterTwo, of course, so in these cases I could simply load the packages after LobsterTwo — but I would also have to remove the code to restore CM in this case, which makes these changes less local.)

In short, I know that I can get CM back if I want to use LobsterTwo (or a similar font) *sometimes*, but want CM to be the default. But it is slightly fiddly and requires non-local maintenance when I want to use a different default typeface. It would be better if I could keep LobsterTwo from being made the default typeface in the first place, or to undo it immediately afterwards.

Surely by *now* there is a workflow to do this gracefully. But what is it?

Comment: According to the sources the font (rm) is set directly. Not sure why they do this and provide `\LobsterTwo`

Comment: The package code indeed contains `\renewcommand*\rmdefault{\LobsterTwofamily}`. I find this an unhappy design choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends entirely on the package, which like any package whether or not font related has a lot of flexibility in the commands it defines.

Looking at `LobsterTwo.sty` the last few lines show

```
  \def\LobsterTwofamily{Lbstr-LF}
  \renewcommand*\rmdefault{\LobsterTwofamily}
  \newcommand*\LobsterTwo{\fontfamily{\LobsterTwofamily}\selectfont}
```

so it has defined an NFSS family `Lbstr-LF` which can be used like `cmr` family denoting Computer Modern Roman.

Then it also makes that family the default Roman font and defines the `\LobsterTwo` command to switch back to that.

```
\let\oldrmdefault\rmdefault
\usepackage{LobsterTwo}
\let\rmdefault\oldrmdefault
```

is probably what you want, as the package doesn't seem to have an option not to redefine the default.

Comment: this is describing the T1 workflow for pdftex/latex, the `fontspec` workflow for xetex/luatex is similar (using `\setmainfont` o changing the default)

Comment: Thanks! As work-arounds go, this is local and simple.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend that you use modern fonts in LuaTeX when you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts in PDFTeX when you have to.  [Lobster Two is a conversion of an OpenType font.](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lobster-two)

If you download it and run

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{LobsterTwo}[
  Scale = MatchUppercase ,
  Ligatures = Common ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf ]
```

You will not have this problem, and will also get all of its ligatures.

You could also load another font package after that one, overriding its font settings.